# Avoid abstract to be aligned vertically

Tags: alignment, abstract

My abstract is aligned vertically. I would like it to be centered horizontally but at the top of the page.

Here's my code:

```
\thispagestyle{plain}

\begin{abstract}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{abstract}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
\end{abstract}
```

It's probably caused by the copyright that comes just before it:

```
\vspace*{\fill}
\begingroup
\centering
\copyright \: Me\\
\vspace{15pt}
Lorem Ipsum

\endgroup
\vspace*{\fill}

\pagebreak
```

These two sections are included in my document

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage[english]{babel}

\usepackage{sectsty}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[acronym, automake]{glossaries}

\usepackage{indentfirst}

\usepackage[backend=biber, style=apa, sorting=none]{biblatex}

\title{title}
\author{Me}
\date{}
\usepackage{fullpage}

\edef\restoreparindent{\parindent=\the\parindent\relax}
\usepackage{parskip}
\restoreparindent

\makeindex


\begin{document}


\chapterfont{\centering}

\pagebreak
\input{Copyright}

\input{Abstract}



\tableofcontents{}


\chapter{Introduction}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.



\pagebreak


\section{State of the art}


\printbibliography

\listoffigures



\end{document}
```

How could I prevent the vertical alignment from happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default the `abstract` in the `report` class is put on a `titlepage` between two first-order infinitely stretchable `\vfil` to center it vertically on the page. The quickest way to override this is to introduce at the abstract's end a second-order glue `\vfill` (two `l` instead of one).

```
\documentclass{report}

\begin{document}

\begin{abstract}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor
incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
\end{abstract}

\begin{abstract}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor
incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.\vfill % <--- THIS
\end{abstract}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

[image: a]

Try this code

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage[english]{babel}

\usepackage{sectsty}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[acronym, automake]{glossaries}
\makeglossaries

\usepackage{indentfirst}

\usepackage[backend=biber, style=apa, sorting=none]{biblatex}

\title{title}
\author{Me}
\date{}
\usepackage{fullpage}

\edef\restoreparindent{\parindent=\the\parindent\relax}
\usepackage{parskip}
\restoreparindent

\makeindex  
\begin{document}
    
\chapterfont{\centering}    

%% Title page
\maketitle

%% copyright page
\thispagestyle{empty}
\vspace*{\fill}
\begin{center}      
    \copyright \: Me\\
    \vspace{15pt}
    Lorem Ipsum
\end{center}
\vspace*{\fill}
\newpage

%% Abstract page    
{\centering \textbf{Abstract}\par} %centered title at the beginning of the  page or use \begin{center} ... \end{center}
\vspace{\baselineskip} %Added space below the first line
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Abstract} % add Abstract to the table of contents

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.

\tableofcontents    % starts a new page

\chapter{Introduction}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.

\newpage    

\section{State of the art}
    
\printbibliography

\listoffigures
    
\end{document}
```

Comment: It seems to work. Could you tell me what ``{\centering \textbf{Abstract}\par}
\vspace{\baselineskip}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Abstract}``does?

Comment: There are five commands and the braces. The best way is to remove one, compile  and see the effect on the Abstract page (and the table of content}.